# Should I report an inappropriate remark at work if my friend is the one who said it?

Tags: unprofessional-behavior, behavior

My employee/ friend made an inappropriate remark in front of another employee who was offended by the remark. I feel obligated to report it?

Comment: How did you know, and how did the person making the remark did not? And if they did, what was the aftereffect?

Comment: You call these 2 people "**employees**". Are you their manager, supervisor, or team lead ? Or are you just their coworker ?

Comment: You gave us zero information. What are you expecting us to tell you?

Answer (score 8):

**It depends**

In my opinion, your obligation to report it is correlated with the seriousness of the remark.

For example - someone referring to PAs as 'Silly Girls' - whilst demeaning and condescending, is not in the same vein as say referring to someone of African Descent as a N....r

It also depends on the Context - two employees bantering on their lunch break making a few off-colour remarks and jabs at each other or venting about customers, is not the same seriousness of saying something derogatory in say a board meeting or in front of a customer or client.

Finally - my general view is that the person who is offended by a remark is the only one who has any right to report it. I am not a huge fan of people virtue-signaling offense on behalf of someone else/another group.

There are some exceptions to this - for example if the remark included a threat and the person on the receiving end didn't feel safe to report it - but in such a circumstance, I'm guessing you'd not need to ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

> I feel obligated to report it?

Is that a question?

Perhaps consider letting the offended employee stand up for themself.

Comment: Beware of taking more offense on behalf of someone else than they themselves did. Perhaps just tell the offended party that if they want to raise a formal objection you're willing to  serve as witness. MAINTAIN AGENCY; support people if they want to take action, but respect that they should be the ones deciding how to handle the situation.

Comment: Perhaps consider letting the offended employee believe that you agree with the offending one, in other words? Also, I'm offended when people make excluding and mean comments even when they're not directed at me.

Answer (score 1):

Check for yourself:

- Is the person who was offended somehow reporting the the person making the remark? If no -> they can happily report it to their boss if they like; you could express to them that you don't share the opinion (and imply that you are not "on the side" of your friend)
- Was the remark outside of the bounds of what would be acceptable or tolerable or was it just offending subjectively?
- Do you have a function (team lead) which requires you to intervene?
- are there reporting mechanisms in your company for such behaviour?

Not unlikely that assuming that the person who was offended does not actually need your help (beyond the pointing out to them that you feel sorry for this ans that you don't see it that way, to ensure them that if they decide to step up you are not bound by loyalty to your friend).

Comment: You know, when people said horrible things to me, and later a bystander sought me out to let me know they **totally** disagreed with that and didn't support it and were 100% on my side, I actually didn't feel supported at all and nor did I believe them. Why didn't they say anything at the time? Instead I felt obliged to perform gratitude and praise them for the basic humanity of not agreeing with some offensive humour that had been aired at my expense, and which they were happy to pretend to agree with at the time. YMMV, of course, but I advise to either speak up in the moment or not.

Comment: @KateGregory Not escalating in the moment is very different from "agreeing with it". The cases in which I observed such things (typically sexist remarks) i definitely did not "pretend to agree with it", but i also did not give more attention to it than it already had, also in the interest of letting the target of such things decide how and if to escalate and/or clarify with my manager how they see the situation.

Comment: I don't think "not cool, bro" is escalating. And most observers will see silence as agreeing or at least not objecting. If that's news to you, sit with it for a while. You may be sending messages to your coworkers that you don't intend to send, like that you don't mind certain things you actually find offensive.

Comment: @KateGregory My comment is  a response to you comment, not your answer.

Comment: Your answer is "I would rather not say anything at the time". My comment was "that might be seen as agreeing with the offensive comment." You then said "but I didn't want to escalate" and I pointed out there are things you can say that are not escalating. This is all relevant to this answer, not mine.

Comment: @KateGregory: Stop reading things into my answer which are not there. The original question was not "how should I behaved at that moment", but "it has happened, what to do now", and that's what i answered.

Answer (score 1):

First, the absolutely best thing you can do when you hear inappropriate remarks at work is to rebut them or shut them down right then and there in front of all the people who heard them. Not a big giant speech either. More like:

> Not cool, [name]

or

> That's not ok, [name]

In some relationships, saying their name might make you sound a bit like a parent or teacher, so you could substitute a word like "man" or "dude" or a phrase like "my friend". Practice once or twice alone so you know which phrasing feels like yourself. You are doing your friend/employee a favour by a gentle on-the-spot course correction like this.

People who think it's ok to make inappropriate comments at work (usually because they find them funny) are not likely to change their ways if HR tells them off a month later. They may respond more when nobody likes their comments and some people immediately object to them. More importantly, the target of the comment learns immediately that not everyone here supports whatever views were just being aired.

I recommend **not** mentioning rules or authority:

> You can't say that kind of thing! [here]

> Keep that up and you'll be hearing from HR!

> Don't let [person] hear you talk like that!

These either come across as "buddy I totally agree but you know you can't say it out loud, you'll get in trouble" or "I can cost you your job". Neither is helpful here and you can't control which one they will interpret it as.

Having missed that opportunity, I am not sure there is a lot to be gained by going and telling someone, but if I did it might go like this:

> Heads up, you might be getting a complaint or maybe just seeing some tensions in the group soon. A said "B" to C and honestly, none of us really appreciated it.

You need that second half of the sentence to avoid giving the impression that you're warning the boss about whiny C who objects to things everyone else thinks are great.